# Asp.Net TreeView with checkBox selection works only on first page Load.

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, treeview

I am using `TreeView` with `ShowCheckBoxes="All"`. What I want to achieve with below code is that when a user click on `Parent node` all the `child nodes` get `selected`. :

[image]

This code works only on first page load. E.g. I click on "`Fruits`" and all the `child nodes` get selected and when I click again then all the `child nodes` get deselected. So far so good. But when I click on the  "`Fruits`" again then the `child nodes` don't get selected. I think the problem is somewhere in my `jquery` code.

**ascx file:**

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All"></asp:TreeView>
```

**code behind:**

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Fruits", "Fruits"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Mango", "Mango"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Apple", "Apple"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Pineapple", "Pineapple"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Orange", "Orange"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Grapes", "Grapes"));

                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Vegetables", "Vegetables"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Carrot", "Carrot"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Cauliflower", "Cauliflower"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Potato", "Potato"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Tomato", "Tomato"));
                TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Onion", "Onion"));

            }
```

**ascx file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("[id*=TreeView1] input[type=checkbox]").bind("click", function () {
                var table = $(this).closest("table");
                if (table.next().length > 0 && table.next()[0].tagName == "DIV") {
                    //Is Parent CheckBox
                    var childDiv = table.next();
                    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
                    $("input[type=checkbox]", childDiv).each(function () {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //Is Child CheckBox
                    var parentDIV = $(this).closest("DIV");
                    if ($("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV).length == $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", parentDIV).length) {
                        $("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV.prev()).attr("checked", "checked");
                    } else {
                        $("input[type=checkbox]", parentDIV.prev()).removeAttr("checked");
                    }
                }
            });


        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .prop instead, attr can sometimes have strange behaviour.

Checked

```
.prop('checked',true);
```

Unchecked

```
.prop('checked',false);
```